# I need a perspective transformation for a crooked rectangle

Tags: c#, rotation, transform

Is there some way to rotate an image in a certain way? I will explain it to you: I do **not** want the rotation in the sense of `PictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)`, or as shown  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Ju9.png), but rather orient a crooked rectangle to the camera (being flush with the camera).

I made a [drawing for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNkn3.png). This is a view from above. Imagine, you are the person who is standing at point (0, 0) and currently taking a picture of the body („Rechteck“). I want to rotate that image by a certain angle, for example 35°, because you stood 35° to the body (perspectively).

I've already prepared some source code and did the math for that.
The code works like follows: The user has to enter the distance from himself to the center of the rectangle, as well as the angle. In the attached picture this is the red line. You also need to know how wide the rectangle is. The program calculates the x and y coordinates (`x_v` and `y_v`). The program calculates all distances and angles from the left edge of the rectangle to the right edge.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace schiefes_Rechteck
{
    public partial class Form_Main : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// entered angle in degrees 
        /// </summary>
        private Int16 eingegebener_Winkel_in_Grad;
        private UInt16 Radius_in_mm;
        /// <summary>
        /// Length of the rectangle in mm 
        /// </summary>
        private UInt16 Laenge_des_Rechtecks_in_mm;
        /// <summary>
        /// all distances [mm]
        /// </summary>
        private List<double> alle_Entfernungen = new List<double>();
        /// <summary>
        /// all angles [°]
        /// </summary>
        private List<double> alle_Winkel = new List<double>();
        public Form_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(148, 148, 109);
            this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            Button_Start.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(194, 194, 165);
            TextBox_Entfernung.Text = "1300";
            TextBox_Winkel.Text = "35";
            TextBox_Rechtecklaenge.Text = "503";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\schiefes_Rechteck_Grafik.PNG"))
            {
                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\schiefes_Rechteck_Grafik.PNG");
            }
        }

        private void Form_Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                PictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            }
            if (PictureBox2.Image != null)
            {
                PictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_Entfernung_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_Entfernung.Text))
            {
                bool erfolgreich = UInt16.TryParse(TextBox_Entfernung.Text, out Radius_in_mm);
                if (erfolgreich)
                {
                    TextBox_Entfernung.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 163, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox_Entfernung.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(163, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_Winkel_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_Winkel.Text))
            {
                bool erfolgreich = Int16.TryParse(TextBox_Winkel.Text, out eingegebener_Winkel_in_Grad);
                if (erfolgreich)
                {
                    TextBox_Winkel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 163, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox_Winkel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(163, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
      
        private void TextBox_Rechtecklaenge_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_Rechtecklaenge.Text))
            {
                bool erfolgreich = UInt16.TryParse(TextBox_Rechtecklaenge.Text, out Laenge_des_Rechtecks_in_mm);
                if (erfolgreich)
                {
                    TextBox_Rechtecklaenge.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 163, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox_Rechtecklaenge.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(163, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        private async void Button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            await Task.Run(() => Berechnung_aller_Werte());
        }

        private void Berechnung_aller_Werte()
        {
            alle_Entfernungen.Clear();
            alle_Winkel.Clear();

            double x_v, y_v; // Mitte des Rechtecks, davon die x-Koordinate und die y-Koordinate. 
            x_v = Radius_in_mm * Math.Cos((90.0 - (double)eingegebener_Winkel_in_Grad) * Math.PI / 180.0); //richtig
            y_v = Radius_in_mm * Math.Sin((90.0 - (double)eingegebener_Winkel_in_Grad) * Math.PI / 180.0); //richtig

            double alpha_in_Grad = 0.0;
            double Entfernung = 0.0;
            double halbe_Rechteckbreite = Laenge_des_Rechtecks_in_mm / 2.0;
            double Position_linker_Rand = x_v - halbe_Rechteckbreite; //richtig

            double Zaehler = 0.0;

            while (Zaehler < Laenge_des_Rechtecks_in_mm)
            {
                alpha_in_Grad = Math.Atan((Position_linker_Rand + Zaehler) / y_v) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
                alle_Winkel.Add(alpha_in_Grad);
                Entfernung = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Position_linker_Rand + Zaehler, 2) + Math.Pow(y_v, 2));
                alle_Entfernungen.Add(Entfernung);
                Zaehler += 1.0;
            }
            this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { ListBox1.Items.Add(Math.Round(alle_Entfernungen.Last(), 0).ToString() + " mm"); ListBox1.Items.Add(Math.Round(alle_Winkel.Last(), 0).ToString() + " °"); }));
        }
    }//Form
}
```

Comment: See: [3D projection / Perspective projection (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection). I think that the "Weak perspective projection" would be enough. Basically for each pixel you have `xProjected = x/distance` and `yProjected = y/distance` (times a scaling factor).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you so far. I have to read myself into the subject. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I watched this video https://youtu.be/Gu9mSHwI3ec. I also read through the text "Affine Transformations". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation I think I need the affine warping ? I don't currently know how to set up the formulas?

Comment: It depends whether you want an orthogonal projection where distant things have the same size as near things and parallel lines remain parallel, then you can use an affine transformation (just scale down the x-axis) OR whether you want a real perspective where distant things look smaller, then you will need a projective transformation.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes ok, the following: when I stand at the point (0/0), as shown in the picture in the appendix, then I see the black rectangle crooked. So I mean, from the human point of view, the rectangle is crooked, so its right edge is smaller than the left (because the right edge is further away). I want to fix the "problem", so I want the rectangle to be the same size everywhere from my point of view. So it is flush with the camera. So what transformation do I have to do? I seek an orthogonal projection made by affine transformation, right?  I appreciate your help 

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-crooked image, i.e., all lines remain either vertical or horizontal, then all what happens to the image is that its width will appear smaller when viewed from the side, and its height will remain the same.

Get the scaling factor for the x-Axis by dividing the apparent angle under which you see the image, i.e., the angle between the yellow-green and the pink lines in your image, by the corresponding angle you would have when standing right in front of the image. A very good approximation for this factor is simply `cos(36° * PI / 180)`, where the angle is the angle to your red line in the image.

```
xScale = Math.Cos(angleToMidLineInDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
yScale = 1;
```

or simply

```
xScale = Math.Cos(angleToMidLineInRadians);
yScale = 1;
```

where

```
angleToMidLineInRadians = Math.ATan(x_redLine / y_v);
```

or in one step

```
xScale = y_v / Math.Sqrt(x_redLine * x_redLine + y_v * y_v);
```

See: [cos(arctan(x/y))](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28arctan%28x%2Fy%29%29) on WolframAlpha.

---

However, when transforming an image, you must do the inverse transformation (as explained towards the end of the [video](https://youtu.be/Gu9mSHwI3ec)), because you want to determine the pixels of the transformed image. I.e., you will do in pseudo code (where `t` means transformed and without `t` are the coordinates in the original):

```
for (yt = 0 to height_t - 1; yt++) {
    for (xt = 0 to width_t - 1; xt++) {
        (x, y) = inverse_transformation(xt, yt);
        color_t = get_color(picture, x, y);
        draw(picture_t, xt, yt, color_t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks ! This afternoon, I had a little trouble implementing the whole thing. Before you edited your answer, I discovered the `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix` and I first had to get the image converted to a matrix. That works. However, your / our approach is not sufficient. I took a picture and measured everything (distance and angle). It doesn't work 100%. I also had to use 1 ÷ , so that the image goes in the correct direction..(`matrix2.Scale((float)(1.0 / Math.Cos(eingegebener_Winkel_in_Grad * Math.PI / 180.0)), 1F);`) That's probably due to the Matrix class.